# How to call other class method with out parameter

Tags: c#, out

Why can I not call another class's method with out parameter? For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i =10;
        int j = OtherClass.Test(i);
    }
}

class OtherClass
{
    public static int Test(out int i)
    {
        i = 30;
        return i+15;
    }
}
```

I get "The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication2.OtherClass.Test(out int)' has some invalid arguments" error??
How can I do this? I need to call some general static methods with some out parameters.

Thanks

Comment: `OtherClass.Test(out i);` Next time please use google or [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) first

Comment: Oh my God!!!, forget it, Thanks, I confused between some complex implementations and forget a simple requirement, Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller program will be like below:

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       int i;
       int j = OtherClass.Test( out i);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your method like this:

```
int j = OtherClass.Test(out i);
```

You should also understand that by doing that you'll change the value of 'i' variable that you pass as a parameter to Test method.

More specifically: after execution of Test method the value of 'i' will be set to 30.